# Ubuntu 14.04 AMD Dual Graphics 8650G / 8670M

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I have a HP Pavillion Laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It has an AMD APU with integrated 8650G and a discrete AMD 8670M GPUs.

```
ajith@SoulCube:~$ uname -a
Linux SoulCube 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ajith@SoulCube:~$
```

I am using the fglrx driver installed using the 'Additional Drivers' tool

I have read that the dual graphics will switch back and forth between the iGPU and the dGPU according to workload, but my laptop seems to be not doing that.

I had tried `fglrxinfo` but it only shows the iGPU and does not list the dGPU.

```
ajith@SoulCube:~$ fglrxinfo 
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 8650G
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005

ajith@SoulCube:~$
```

When I tried `lspci | grep Radeon` I got the following

```
ajith@SoulCube:~$ lspci | grep Radeon
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
ajith@SoulCube:~$
```

I am curious as to why the dGPU is listed as a Display Controller and not a VGA Compatible Controller. A lot of the Posts I have seen on the internet indicate that both of them should turn up as a VGA Compatible controller.

Can somebody help me understand the issue and help me switch permanently to using my discrete GPU. I have checked the BIOS for options pertaining to this but they are not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging in google and found out at ubuntuforums that `gpu-manager` was causing the confusion.

I tried doing `aticonfig --initial --adapter=1` to generate an `xorg.conf` file, but the file was getting replaced with an near empty file on reboot.

On reboot my system will default to the integrated GPU. I guess its the driver making this decision on account of the `xorg.conf` file being incomplete.

I stumbled upon a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489 which helped me solve the problem (temporarily atleast).

The temporary solution in the bug report was to comment out the `start on` lines at the beginning of the file `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf` which should prevent the gpu-manager being started when `lightdm` started and replaced my `xorg.conf` file.

I have to read up on these to get a more concrete idea.